# Time and speed problems:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Rahim covered 1/3 of his total Journey by bus,1/6 of his total Journey
>   by car and the rest of the Journey by train.If the speeds of the
>   train,car and bus are 60km/hr,80km/hr and 50km/hr respectively then
>   what was the average speed of Rahim during entire Journey?

I have tried:

For time and speed problems for calculating the average speed we need to know the total distance and total time

let x be the distance so 1/3*x,1/6*x and 1/2*x respectively,speed  have given

I am calculating the total time

total time = (1/3*x + 1/6 *x + 1/2*x )/60+80+50 = x/190

for average speed = total distance/total time = x/(x/190) = 190

**but answer is 58.5 km/hr , what i am doing wrong , please anyone rectify my mistake**

Answer (score 4):

The average velocity is: $v_{avg}=\dfrac{displacement}{time}$, and we know that the total time is: $\Delta t=\dfrac{\Delta displacement}{velocity_{avg}}$. Say the total distance is $n$ kilometers. So the distances covered by bus, car and train, are $\dfrac{n}{3}, \dfrac{n}{6}$ and $\dfrac{n}{2}$ kilometers, respectively. The overall distance obviously, is $n$. So we just have to calculate the total time which according to the second formula will be:

$\Delta t = \Delta t_{bus} + \Delta t_{car} + \Delta t_{train} = \dfrac{n/3}{50} + \dfrac{n/6}{80} + \dfrac{n/2}{60} = \dfrac{41n}{2400}$

So the average speed (scalar quantity) is:

$\dfrac{n}{\dfrac{41n}{2400}} = \dfrac{2400}{41}$

Which is approximately $58.53$.

Comment: ok thank you i have understand what i am doing mistake